# Unexpected return value of istream object while using rdbuf(NULL)

Tags: c++, io

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //RETURN VALUE IS NULL AS CIN IS SET TO A BUFFER POINTED BY THE RDBUF'S ARGUMENT
    if(cin.rdbuf(NULL)==NULL)     
    {
        cout<<cin.rdstate()<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:** `1`

While running this code I found that the return value of function `rdbuf` with the associated `istream` object is `NULL` while the return value of `rdstate` is **1** which represents that *failbit* has been set where as I was expecting *badbit* to be set and the return value to be **4**.

When `istream` object is associated with `NULL` then shouldn't it be a sign of corrupt stream?

Comment: Note that the only specified [I/O state flag](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) is `goodbit` (which is defined as zero). The rest of the flags are implementation defined. So you need to check and compare against the actual flags to see what `1` might represent in your implementation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks a lot!! I checked it and `failbit` is **4** on my system, `badbit` is **1**